# Should I update normalize.css when I use boostrap css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, normalize-css

I know that bootstrap 3.3.7 already includes normalize.css 3.0.3 But there is version 8.0.0 already. Should I add link to normalize.css 8.0.0 before link to bootstrap 3.3.7?

Comment: One question - has it got something you need that the older version doesn't?  If yes, then upgrade it, if not then don't bother unless you want to (but as you're not upgrading bootstrap to the latest version, I wouldn't see why you would want everything else on the latest versions)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap already included normalize.css

[check this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-normalize)

As per their documentation, they said - **For improved cross-browser rendering, we use Normalize.css** So Don't need to include Normalize file.